# Как скрыть текст(информацию) на сайте

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Возможно вопрос покажется тупым,но все же. У меня есть сайт с профилем.В профиле показывается информация(твои соц сети) человек хочет их скрыть,чтобы другие пользователи не смогли ее увидеть.Как так сделать?

Comment: Раз в метках показывается `php`, то скройте их отображение в условие, чтобы показывалось только если юзер смотрит свой профиль.

Comment: в бд для users создаешь колонку, например, hide_social, где 1 - скрыто, 0 - показано. Когда юзер меняет состояние - меняешь 1 на 0 или наоборот. В скрипте проверяешь. Если у пользователя hide_social == 0, тогда показываешь социалки. Если == 1, то выводишь сообщение, что пользователь скрыл социалочки. Делов то

Comment: Спасибо, но если пользователь хочет что-то одно скрыть, то нужно для каждой информации делать стобец. Там hide_vk , hide_telegram .  Ищю способ как легче, но все равно спасибо

Comment: @Venom: нет, не для каждой - только для списка социалок и списка скрытых.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, по какой-то причине будет неудобно/невозможно добавить столбцы/столбец в таблицу с пользователями. Тогда можно сделать так:

если таблица `users` имеет примерно такой вид:
`user_id`(1, 2, 3) ...

То можно добавить 2 таблицы:

таблица: `social` (social_id, social_slug ...)

| social_id | social_slug |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | vk |
| 2 | tg |

таблица: `soc_user_hide_entries` (entry_id, social_id, user_id)

| entry_id | social_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |

Пользователь в личном кабинете скрыл какую-то соцсеть: в БД в таблицу `soc_user_hide_entries` добавилась запись. Пользователь c `user_id` === 1 сделал видимой соцсеть `vk` для просмотра: из таблицы `soc_user_hide_entries` удалилась соответствующая запись.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите предоставить пользователю возможность скрыть только выбранные им соц.сети, то в таблице с отображаемой о пользователе информации добавляете ещё одну колонку, куда будут заноситься названия нужных соц.сетей. Это будут индикаторы, по которым на сайте можно будет понять, какие ссылки нужно выставлять на обозрения, а какие нужно скрыть.